Are Brahmins allowed to hunt for leisure?
Can Brahmins hunt for fun as per scripture?

Certainly not if he desires to attain spiritual perfection. Even a Kshatriya who is allowed to hunt as per the Shastras incurs some sins by doing so. https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/51/62/

@HariHara Gaudiya Vaishnavas are authentic, but Isckon isn't and the Ramayana and Rama disagree with you look at the killing of Vali answer.

Please provide more context on how the killing of Vali relates to this if possible. That verse is from the Bhagavata Purana and has nothing to do with Iskcon or Gaudiya Vaishnavism.

The Brahmana Jada Bharata in his last life was careful while walking as to not knowingly step on ants then what to speak of hunting. https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/10/2/

@HariHara I was speaking of Kshatryia and in times of desperation a  brahmin may hunt

Yes, emergency is different than doing it with the intent of fun.

@HariHara indeed I am asking for leisure though and it is stated for Kshatryia's in Mahabharta that hunting is allowed.
